# Consistently retrieving cookie and crumb from yahoo finance for historical data download

Tags: python, cookies, yahoo-finance

I am working on a project involving downloading historical stock price data from yahoo finance. A step in this process involves determining the correct cookie and crumb to use with a url to download the data. The code I currently have only works sometimes, i.e., the stock data is retrieved with out any problems, and will fail at seemingly random iterations. In the full problem, I am downloading data for multiple stocks. The problem I am encountering is a lack of consistency in retrieving the data. I run into an issue where the data that comes back is

```
b'{\n"finance":{\n"error":{\n"code":"Unauthorized",\n"description":"Invalid cookie"\n}\n}\n}\n
```

So, I believe the problem lies in the cookie retrieval set.

To test the issue, I wrote a little script that attempts to download data for the same stock over 20 iterations. When running this, I will typically have about 18 or so iterations that work properly, and the others will not work. The iterations in which this happens changes each time I execute the test script.

Here is the test code I have been using thus far:

```py
import requests
import time
import re
for k in range(20):
    symbol='AMZN'
    url="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/?p=%s" % (symbol, symbol)
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
    cookie = r.cookies
    lines = r.content.decode('latin-1').replace('\\', '')
    lines = lines.replace('}', '\n')
    lines = lines.split('\n')
    for l in lines:
        if re.findall(r'CrumbStore', l):
            crumb = l.split(':')[2].strip('"')
    start_date = int(int(time.time())-15*86400)
    end_date = int(time.time())
    url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/%s?period1=%s&period2=%s&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=%s" % (symbol, start_date, end_date, crumb)
    response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie, timeout=10)
    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        print(block)
        print(k)
```

I would expect this to return the stock price data each time, similar to:

```
b'Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume\n2019-06-06,1737.709961,1760.000000,1726.130005,1754.359985,1754.359985,3689300\n2019-06-07,1763.699951,1806.250000,1759.489990,1804.030029,1804.030029,4808200\n2019-06-10,1822.000000,1884.869995,1818.000000,1860.630005,1860.630005,5371000'
```

however, I get the error sometimes. Is there a more reliable way to ensure the data is downloaded properly? I know that I am able to access and download it, but the code is unreliable.

Note that this is similar to trying to access the data with a bad cookie/crumb directly in a browser, for example via the url:

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AMZN?period1=1559367165&period2=1560663165&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=ODCkS0u002FOZyL
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Actually was trying to figure out how to apply the cookie correctly to the URL. Let me know if you found a stable fix for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to your code. It is on the Yahoo-server side. I see that the issue is totally random. If you hit an invalid cookie, then you continuously get invalid cookies. I guess the loop cannot help you to jump over this problem.

Maybe, you can save a working cookie and crumb pair once. And you can load this pair to get data.

```
# Save cookie.
with open('cookie', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cookie, f)
```

Loading cookie is:

```
# Load cookie.
with open('cookie', 'rb') as f:
    session.cookies.update(pickle.load(f))
```

Comment: Hi @bozcani! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't simply put links to other pages. While the link may actually contains the answer, it's always best to explain thoroughly. Also, the answer may become invalid if the links stop to work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Ashkan! I just updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly this issue, trying to download historical data for a list of stocks. I fixed it using the brute force method, iterating 5 times over each request then breaking out of the loop if the request succeeds. If the request works, the first few characters returned are "Date,Open".

```
    String crumb = getCrumb(securityID); // get the crumb

    String yahooQuery = "?period1=" + fromDate + "&period2=" + toDate + 
    "&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=" + crumb;

    String requestURL = 
    "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" + securityID + 
    yahooQuery;

    PostRequest stockDetail = new PostRequest(requestURL);

    for (int tries = 0; tries < 5; tries++) {

        // Get history CSV file
        stockDetail.send();

        if (stockDetail.getContent().contains("Date,Open")) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```